# How to set and get custom attributes of layers in OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers

In OpenLayers library I create layers like so:

```
var layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM()
});
...
```

What I want to do is to add some unique attribute to this layer, or something like:

```
var layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM(),
    customAttr: 'unique_id'
});
...
```

so that, later I could do this:

```
map.getLayers().forEach(function(layer){
    if(layer.customAttr === 'unique_id'){
        doSomething();
    }
});
```

I do not know how to do this in practice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `if(layer.customAttr === 'unique_id')` to `if(layer.get("customAttr") === 'unique_id')` and it should work. See [this](https://jsfiddle.net/itsyahani/67g2hhyw/) fiddle.